# Finding number 2017 using 1,2,3,4,5,6

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

i found this question on a monthly magazine and i simply can't solve it. To elaborate, the person is required to find number 2017 using numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6 with following rules:

- Only operations allowed are  +,-,*,/.
- You can use any number of parentheses.
- You can string numbers like forming 1234 from 1,2,3,4 as long as it maintains the initial order of 1,2,3,4,5,6 e.g. (123+4)*(5/6).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of $(123+4)*(5/6)$ ? In such puzzles, the division operator is always taken for granted, though it can be understood in at least three ways: exact division only, integer division or fractions allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: use that $2016 = 36\cdot 56$.

> $$2017 = 1 + (2+34)\cdot 56.$$

I believe that the solution is unique.